# Control pointer using keyboard on Freya

Tags: mouse, keyboard, accessibility

How can I control pointer using keyboard instead of mouse on elementary OS Freya?

Universal Access > Pointing and Clicking > Mouse keys (turn on) ... yeah it works but pointer's speed is ridiculously slow and Options sections and Mouse settings are not available. Any third party application can handle it or maybe exist native or more traditional solution for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

**xkbset** can be used to set various options available  in  the  XKB
       extensions.   This  includes such things as mousekeys where one can use
       the numeric pad keys to move the mouse;

---

### Execution

#### Open Terminal

install xkbset with:

```
sudo apt-get install xkbset
```

after successfull installation type:

```
xkbset ma 60 10 10 5 2
```

or try your own values. here the options

```
xkbset ma [delay] [interval] [time to max] [max speed] [curve]
```

---

### Note

after every shutdown or reboot you had to activate it again or you create a little autostart option

#### Autostart `xkbset ma 60 10 10 5 2`

- go to `Settings -> applications -> autostart`
- there you can add an application to start after login. We use the custom command field to
  enter our command like the picture below
- after entering the command press enter to activate it.

---

[image]

Comment: Just a note, there is a bug with mousekeys (and a kludgy workaround) noted at the end of [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1977588&page=2)